# What is $P(X > Y)$?

Tags: probability

I can't type the table but, I have pasted it. The question is Find$P(X > Y)$?

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|cc}  & 2/10 & 4/10 & 4/10
\\  & \uparrow & \uparrow & \uparrow
\\ \hline 3 & 1/10 & 2/10 & 1/10 &\to & 4/10
\\ \hline 2 & 0 & 1/10 & 1/10 &\to & 2/10
\\ \hline 1 & 1/10 & 1/10 & 2/10 &\to & 4/10
\\ \hline Y~\backslash~X & 1 &2&3
\\\end{array}$$

- a) Find the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$
- b) Are $X$ and $Y$ independent
- c) Find $P(X>Y)$

(c) I don't know why but this is confusing me up, and I feel that it is probably really simple.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(X > Y)$ is the probability that $X$ is greater than $Y$.

Sum the values in the squares where $X > Y$ (the ones below the bottom left to top right diagonal).

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|cl}  & 2/10 & 4/10 & 4/10 & & \bbox[lemonchiffon]{\bbox[lemonchiffon, 0.1ex,border:dotted 1pt]{\qquad\mid?}=\mathsf P(X>Y)}
\\  & \uparrow & \uparrow & \uparrow & \nearrow
\\ \hline 3 & 1/10 & 2/10 & 1/10 &\to & 4/10
\\ \hline 2 & 0 & 1/10 & \bbox[lemonchiffon, 0.1ex]{1/10} &\to & 2/10
\\ \hline 1 & 1/10 & \bbox[lemonchiffon, 0.1ex]{1/10} & \bbox[lemonchiffon, 0.1ex]{2/10} &\to & 4/10
\\ \hline Y~\backslash~X & 1 &2&3
\\\end{array}$$

Comment: It's just not registering in my head is visually.. would you mind showing the first couple values  in order to get the sum?

Comment: @BoredPerson I told you exactly which values to add. There are three boxes below the diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(X\gt Y) = P(X=2, Y=1) + P(X=3, Y=2) + P(X=3, Y=1)$$